# Installing LaTeX on Macbook Pro

Tags: installing

I have recently bought Macbook Pro and want to install LaTeX. I am using TeXstudio, but I need to install MiKTeX which I was using earlier in Windows. Please suggest what to install as an alternative to MiKTeX for my Mac.

Comment: Go with MacTeX: http://tug.org/mactex/

Comment: I agree with @Paulo: Texstudio is supported by Mactex, and Mactex is the most used Tex distribution for Macs.

Comment: I also agree with Paolo. Having a mac, using MacTeX and completely satisfied. The package is shipped with several editors and tools.

Comment: Furthermore, MiKTeX is for Windows only. MacTeX is based on TeXLive, more or less the authoritative distribution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cheapest, most stable, most popular option is (as Paulo says) to install [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex).
It is downloadable as an all-in-one package file (`.pkg`); just double-click and you're good to go.

MacTeX comes with a few editors, namely TUG's TeXworks and the acclaimed TeXShop, but you can also get [TeXstudio for Mac](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net) as well.

You will find that, as OS X is a UNIX-based environment, working with TeXnology may prove to be a little simpler than doing so under Windows.

Comment: Right. But you're NOT good to go just yet. When I try to build and compile my LaTex file, I get the following error: "Make sure that you have installed a LaTeX distribution". It probably means that MacTex is installed in a different directory than my Latex folder. How do I solve this?

Comment: @Kristada673 At this point, I'd recommend making a new question with the exact steps you've taken since downloading MacTeX – that way more people other than myself will see the question and be able to help you :-) (It would be worth it to link this older question in your new one as a 'followup' question – then it will also appear indexed in the sidebar to the right.)

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity why do you need MiKTeX? What is a particular TeX functionality you are seeking which is present in MiKTeX but not in MacTeX?

You question actually have a very simple answer and I am going to offer to you even though I am sure it will be down voted by the members of the community. It looks to me that you are very familiar with Windows but not so much with OS X. The good news is that Windows runs better on MAC hardware than on the native PC hardware.

All you need to do is go and by $300 of your favorite operating system. Unlike PC MAC do not have BIOS but Extensible Firmware Interface. Once you brake into it you can install Windows on Macbook Pro just like on any PC. Word of caution though. Once installed Windows will look really ugly as it will miss drivers for most of MAC hardware. No worries Apple people have already sold you hardware so they will give you Windows drivers. You just need to go to Apple store and get [Boot Camp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/). Once you run it, it will automatically detect missing drivers and install it for you. After one more reboot you will have a magnificent Macbook Pro running you beloved Windows. Now you are ready for the final step. You can go download and install MikTeX just like you would do on the regular PC. IIRC the prefered way of installing MikTeX is using ProTeXt distribution.

Disclaimer: I not BS-ing you. I have actually done all of above for my boss who loves Apple hardware but prefers to run Windows mostly because of Microsoft Office product which is his bread and butter. Having compared MS Office Windows and OS X version I could tell you that makes lots of sense.

Comment: There is nothing in Suman's question that implies that s/he has any particular attachment to Windows, so this answer at best is of marginal help. For running TeX, a Unix based OS is almost certainly simpler than a Windows based system, and therefore running MacTeX is generally going to be a better option. Furthermore, the Mac OS is a great OS. Running Windows on a Mac is really only useful if you *require* Windows-only software, which for TeX is most certainly not the case.

Comment: @Alan Munn You are preaching to the choir Alan. I am proud to be one of those old people who have never used any of Microsoft products. My first computer was DEC MicroVAX 3100 :) I have even started using Linux relatively recently due to the nature of my work. UNIX runs in my blood.

Comment: I don't believe Suman need a specific MikTeX feature in his Mac. Surelly he (as me) strarted to use LaTeX with MikTeX and as new Mac user he doesn't know another TeX distributions, so he is asking for what he knows. Now he'll be able to use MacTeX and decide if he likes it o preffer to do a BootCamp as @Pedrag Punosevac suggested.