# Can't edit a document on first install of tex maker

Tags: installing

Just bought myself a new laptop today, a macbook pro.
I am in the middle of doing my masters dissertation so I download tex maker, plug in my usb and get editing what I already have. However for some reason when I add any content it just does not appear on my PDF. This is really confusing me and I guarantee it's something I am stupidly not doing that I should do on first install. Any advice?

Comment: I think you dont have tex distribution yet, texmaker is just an editor.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, if you require a copy of a tex distribution here is one option.  Uninstall that version TeXmaker.  Go to http://miktex.org/.  Install the basic version of MikTex.

On OS-X (Mac Pro Book) install  MacTex.  This posting provides the details [Installing LaTeX on Macbook Pro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151366/installing-latex-on-macbook-pro)

Now reinstall TeXmaker.  It should now run.  You can test it with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

After you save the above, Press F6 to compile and then F7 to display the pdf.

Comment: doesn't miktex just work soley for windows?

Comment: @ENAFMTH Edited my answer.  Missed the reference to Mac Pro Book.